# SQL CASE expression returning sets based on multiple modes for null and not null

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have task which takes a parameter and has three modes of results

Example
Parameter name is sizePram (1 = only null , 2 = only not null, 3 = both or all)

```
declare @sizeParam int
set @sizeParam = 1 or 2 or 3

select * from SalesLT.Product where Size =
CASE @sizeParam
    when 1 then is null
    when 2 then is not null
    when 3 then all
end
```

Comment: `CASE` is an expression that returns a specific data type. It is not for control of flow logic or to compare things that aren't specific values like `is not null`. You will need to do this using logic other than `CASE`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select * 
from SalesLT.Product 
where 
    (@sizeParam = 1 and Size is null) or
    (@sizeParam = 2 and Size is not null) or
    (@sizeParam = 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
    FROM SalesLT.Product
    WHERE (@sizeParam = 1 AND Size IS NULL)
       OR (@sizeParam = 2 AND Size IS NOT NULL)
       OR (@sizeParam = 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
  FROM SalesLT.Product
 WHERE ( sizeParam <> 1 OR Size IS NULL )
       AND NOT ( sizeParam = 2 AND Size IS NULL );
```